# Xamarin + Visual Studio don´t recognize iPhone 6 S

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I have to develop a demo app using Xamarin + Visual Studio Community 2015.
I am completely new with this technology.
I have connected using USB one iPhone 6S to my Windows 10.
My problem is that Visual Studio does not recognize iPhone device.

Can you help me? Perhaps this device is not suitable for this development?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going wrong. In order to test your IOS app on any physical device, you need a mac machine which will be remotely connected. Before deploying your application to a device, you need to have an active subscription to Apple's Developer Program or use Free Provisioning. Go through this [link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/device_provisioning/) for better understanding. In case if you want to test your IOS app you can have IOS simulator for windows. For installation details [click here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/windows/ios-simulator/).

You can not deploy your app on ios app from windows machine connecting via USB cable.

Comment: I have installed IOS simulator, I have selected Debug + iPhoneSimulator. When running VS ask me for one MAC Agent. I believed that app will run in the simulator with no device connected. Am I wrong? Thanks for your help an patience.

Comment: @Pedro a Mac is always needed and you have to configure the agent on Mac side.

Comment: The last sentence might not be correct. With the Windows side simulator and USB remoting, the actual deployment process can be transparent to developers. Microsoft and Xamarin demonstrated that earlier this year. Not sure when they can finally deliver the final build instead of preview build to developers.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I´ll try other options.